# xmlHttpRequest submitted to PHP script does not return an associative array

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I'm testing out the following script which sends a javascript object using xmlHttpRequest to a php script. Problem is, the array generated by when using xmlHttpRequest is not the same when using form.

Eg: data from form submitted

```
<form action="form-b.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="Newton" value="Gravity"><br>
<input type="text" name="Albert" value="Energy"><br>
<input type="text" name="Edison" value="Bulb"><br>
<input type="text" name="Tesla" value="AC"><br>
<input type="text" name="Bill" value="Microsoft"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

form-b.php
echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';

Array
(
    [Newton] => Gravity
    [Albert] => Energy
    [Edison] => Bulb
    [Tesla] => AC
    [Bill] => Microsoft
)
```

Using xmlHttpRequest

```
var button = $("button")
button.on("click",function() {

    var arr = {
    "Newton": "Gravity",
    "Albert": "Energy",
    "Edison": "Bulb",
    "Tesla": "AC",
    "Bill" : "Microsoft"
};

myData = JSON.stringify(arr);

console.log(myData);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('POST','form-b.php', true);

xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(ajaxReturn(xhr) == true) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
}

function ajaxReturn(x){
    if(x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200){
        return true;
    }
}

xhr.send(myData)

});

form-b.php
echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';

Array
(
    [{"Newton":"Gravity","Albert":"Energy","Edison":"Bulb","Tesla":"AC"}] => 
)
```

The array received when using an xmlHttpRequest is quite different from what would be received when submitting a form.

Where am I going wrong and how can I correct this?

I trying to get the array from $_POST like this

```
Array
(
    [Newton] => Gravity
    [Albert] => Energy
    [Edison] => Bulb
    [Tesla] => AC
    [Bill] => Microsoft
)
```

Comment: The data format is incorrect, PHP can't read JSON, you've to format the request body by x-www-form-urlencoded rules. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST

Comment: Format the request body at the sending or receiving script?

Comment: When making the request with AJAX.

Comment: I already do that in the script `xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`

Comment: Please re-read my first comment: "_you've to format the request body by x-www-form-urlencoded rules_". Currently `myData` is a JSON string, not "_[URL-encoded] key-value tuples separated by '&', with a '=' between the key and the value_".

Comment: Ok. So how is that done?

Comment: ?? `myData = 'Newton=Gravity&Albert=Energy&Edison=Bulb&Tesla=AC&Bill=Microsoft';`.

Comment: You mean do it manually? There's no method to do that using javascript?

Comment: Sure, just iterate through the keys in `arr` (which has a confusing name as being an object), and create the string.

Comment: ... Or as you seem to use jQuery, why not use its [post method](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/#jQuery-post-url-data-success-dataType), it can utilize a plain object as data, you wouldn't need to do any conversions.